# unexpected result when adding months to a date

Tags: php, date

I need to add 3 months to a date until passing a certain date:

```
  $next_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2015-12-31 00:00:00'));
  while($next_dt <= '2016-11-07 00:00:00'){
       $next_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 months",strtotime($next_dt)));      
  }
```

the result of this addition is 2017-01-01 00:00:00
while i am expecting the result to be 2016-12-31 00:00:00

if i am adding 12 months at once the result is correct

```
$orig_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2015-12-31 00:00:00'));
$next_dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+12 months", strtotime($orig_dt)));
```

but i cannot know in advance how many months i will need to add

what shall I do?

Answer (score -1):

Using strtotime() and '+1 month' is troublesome because it doesn't work exactly as one would expect.

To put it more simple, strtotime('+1 month', ...) seems to just add 30 days regardless of the month. For certain months this is a problem because not all months have 30 days.

I would not use '+1 month' to do this, what i used to do is go through each month one by one and just get the last day of the month and add 1 more day. It might not be the most elegant solution but it's safer.